# What's the easiest way to send files to a remote computer?

Tags: remote, transfer

Here's the situation:

I'm working on a public computer. I want to process some data using a program installed on my remote Ubuntu computer. I can access the Ubuntu terminal through SSH on my phone, if necessary. I can't install anything on the public computer.

I want to send a file to my Ubuntu computer so I can work on it. Currently what I do is email the file to myself, open the email via terminal, and put the attachment where I want it. This is inconvenient. What I'd like to be able to do, is send the file via email or web app, and have it automatically show up in the directory of my choice, without ever having to use the terminal. Any ideas? The simpler, the better.

Comment: Does your public computer have SSH? You can also consider Dropbox and its web interface.

Comment: What is the OS of the public computer? For Windows, you could consider using [portable WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/portable) from a USB stick.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. It is possible to use an SSH shell in Chrome, but I'd like to avoid it, and I don't think I can access local files that way. Dropbox looks like a good solution, but I'm wondering if there's anything simpler.

Comment: You could set up a torrent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can download files and run .exes (uninstalled of course) you could try FileZilla
https://filezilla-project.org/
Just make sure you download the zip version since you can't install programs. Although FileZilla is mainly for ftp since you have a SSH server installed and running on your remote computer you can use SFTP (**S**SH **F**ile **T**ransfer **P**rotocol).


Daniel